# Powering 12V LED strip thru European hinges

Tags: led, hinges

This is something im planning to do and in fact already half way into building it.

The idea is I'm installing sections of LED strip behind the cabinet door and its on the door itself. This door is framed using plywood and having large rectangular cut-out in the middle which holds transparent glass. When the door is closed display items in the cabinet will be lit brightly by the LEDs but non of the LED will be visible.

Now to provide power to the LED mounted on the hinged door, im going to use the two hinges so that no extra wires needed.

Current draw by LED thru the hinges will be less than 500 mA thus i don't for see  much power loss on the hinges.

Is this method have ever been tried by someone? Is there anything im risking on this attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's been done. For instance some GM cars supplied power to their rear hatch defogger through the hatchback lift springs (you know, that look like shock absorbers and help you lift the hatch).

However hinges are not made *or listed* to carry current, so you may run into trouble with poor contact and arcing at the hinge.

The right way to do that thing is to put a jumper strap across the hinge, made of a [highly flexible braided wire](https://www.mcmaster.com/#braided-wire/=15b1944da7fc4bdbb95bd9bc3964733bjsjb7ace) made for thousands of flex cycles.

Comment: Samples of other ideas, help with the ability to automatically turn off when the door is opened: https://www.summitracing.com/parts/dak-mgs-4?seid=srese1&cm_mmc=pla-google-_-shopping-_-srese1-_-dakota-digital&gclid=CjwKCAiAnsnjBRB6EiwATkM1Xr2OAAxCWylzRV9Fxp3-nzuBeb4WBa-4ewkqtrAw78jbeWbYvMv9NRoCzBQQAvD_BwE.                          And.  https://www.harwin.com/connectors-hardware/spring-loaded-contacts/